# C# loop through two variables

Tags: c#

I have 2 variables **div1, div2** and want to get all value from them.

I can loop through one variable with foreach, but it's possible to get both divs InnerHtml?

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

var div1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'class1')]");
var div2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'class2')]");

                
foreach (HtmlNode div in div1)
{
    String text = div.InnerHtml;
    Debug.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the `div1` and `div2` variables?

Comment: Combine the nodes into 1 list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mcjmzn, @Jonathan, and @Nenad answers are correct as far as printing all `innerHtml`s.

I'm guessing you want to print the first div1 `innerHtml` and then the first div2 `innerHtml`, and then second div1 `innerHtml`, and second div2 `innerHtml`, and so on. You'll want a regular loop instead of a foreach, and add checks to make sure you don't exceed div1 or div2 array lengths:

```
var div1Max = div1.Count;
var div2Max = div2.Count;
var overallMax = Math.Max(div1Max, div2Max);

for(var i = 0; i < overallMax; i++)
{
    if (i < div1Max)
    {
        String text1 = div1[i].InnerHtml;
        Debug.WriteLine(text1);
    }

    if (i < div2Max)
    {
        String text2 = div2[i].InnerHtml;
        Debug.WriteLine(text2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. I know it was my bad because I can't express myself in english too much and I'm sorry I can't accept everyone's answer but I was looking for this so thank you.

Comment: Glad this works. Figuring out how to ask questions takes practice, [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can help with asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Concat` extension method of `IEnumerable` to combine both collections of nodes.

```cs
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

var div1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'class1')]");
var div2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'class2')]");
var allNodes = div1.Concat(div2);
                
foreach (HtmlNode div in allNodes)
{
    String text = div.InnerHtml;
    Debug.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but can I seperate the two divs InnerHtml in the loop?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: I tried to explain better with my poor english, above - sorry but dont want to duplicate comments

Answer (score 0):

Create a container list at the beginning, add the results to it, and then loop through the container list:

```
var nodes = new HtmlNodeCollection();
nodes.Add(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'class1')]"));
nodes.Add(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'class2')]"));

foreach(HtmlNode node in nodes){
    Debug.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
}
```

It is also possible to build up a different query that will get all the `class1`s and `class2`s at the same time:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'class1') or contains(@class,'class2')]");
```

Edit after comment @ 22:24:56Z:

If there is only one result for each selector, you could simplify your approach something like this:

```
var text1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class,'class1')]")?.InnerHtml ?? String.Empty;
var text2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class,'class2')]")?.InnerHtml ?? String.Empty;
```

Those question marks are null-coalescing operators. See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to say that I want to use them separately as strings in the loop

Comment: Then I don't understand what you're asking. Can you please provide sample input (simplified) and sample *desired* output. Thanks.

Comment: I want to put div1 and div2 InnerHTML values to strings and display them seperately. like:`String text1 = div1.InnerHtml;` , `String text2 = div2.InnerHtml;` inside the loop but now you can't refer to div1 or div2 because they are together as "node".

Comment: So it looks like you don't really need to loop at all? Is there more than one result in each of those `SelectNodes` queries? If not, I have edited my comment above with a simpler approach

Comment: Yes, there is more than one result in each of the queries

Comment: then @Nenad 's answer is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply iterate one after another, instead of concatenating, etc?

```cs
foreach (HtmlNode div in div1)
{
    String text = div.InnerHtml;
    Debug.WriteLine(text);
}
foreach (HtmlNode div in div2)
{
    String text = div.InnerHtml;
    Debug.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Comment: Because the data what I get is random, if you iterate one after another you get the same value? I don't think so.

Comment: Of course it's the same as `Concat`. It will list all `class1` divs, then all `class2` divs. Give it a try.